# Macro name same as identifier name but in other file

Tags: c

In *file1.c*
  `#define MAX_N 99`

In *file2.c*
   `int MAX_N=99;`

What happens if I try to link these two files?

Comment: If you concatenated `file1.c` with `file2.c` and tried to compile both of them, you would get, literally, `int 99=99;` which is not valid C; I don't think that's what you're asking?

Comment: there's no problem since a macro definition by itself is compiled to nothing.  if you included hat macro definition in the second file, you'd got it expanded and your declaration of second file would have been compiled as `int 99 = 99;` which is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

> What happens if I try to link these two files?

You cannot link source files.  You must compile them to object files and link those.  In that case, it is relevant that macros are expanded at compile time, therefore macro identifiers have no link-time representation, and thus they do not interact with identifiers appearing in other translation units.

If instead you combined the two source files into one, in the order given, without `#undef`ining the `MAX_N` macro between those two statements, then the resulting program would be invalid, and every compiler I know would reject it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helps!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen as macro is textually relaced in your `file1.c` with `99` (of course if you have used it somewhere in this file) during the preprocessing stage and symbol MAX_N from the `file1.c` will not be present in the object file.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably if you link both files (the result of compilations), and in case they are to be linked together, nothing would happen.

A `#define` preprocessor directive just declares that the identifier to be expanded into the string following it, so evey occurrence in `file1.c` of `MAX_N` gets converted into `99` and the compiler will see `99` in every place you have used the identifier.  The important thing is that no preprocessor directive gets compiled at all, they are all expanded before the compiler proper sees the code.  This is the reason, that if you `#define MAX_N 99` in the second file, the compiler will get the name of the `int MAX_N` variable expanded into `int 99` and that will be an error, as the compiler expects an identifier (which cannot start with a digit) as the declared object.

Macro expansion has been used frequently for identifier renaming in C.  Or for code offuscation.  I'll illustrate this, let's say you have a variable `xmax` that represents the width of something, and you compile your code with

```
cc -Dxmax=aspofjiasf source.c
```

then, every occurrence of `xmax` will be changed into `aspofjiasf` and the result is that your binary will never have a variable named `xmax` anymore, but `aspofjiasf` instead, making the reverse engineering process more difficult.